# PyQGIS Error using standalone script when loading a vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, vector-layer

I've been able to execute the command below in the Python console in QGIS. I am able to execute `from qgis.core import *` and `import qgis.utils` with no errors in the OSGeo4W shell but adding the layer I am still getting `QObject::connect: Cannot connect <null>::raiseError< QString > to QgsVectorLayer::raiseError< QString >`

The script below works in the Python console within QGIS. My paths are set in Environment Variables as: `PYTHONPATH=c:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\python` and `PATH=c:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\bin`

```
from qgis.core import *
import gdal
import qgis.utils

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis", True)
QgsApplication.initQgis()          
print QgsApplication.showSettings()

layer = QgsVectorLayer('/path/to/shapefile_folder/test.shp', 'test', 'ogr')

if not layer.isValid():
    print "Layer failed to load!"

else:
    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

Comment: Have a look at http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/intro.html#using-pyqgis-in-custom-application You're only missing a few lines that must be always present when running Python scripts out of QGIS.

Comment: I've edited the code above. When running the modified code, a pop-up window stating "python.exe has stopped working" shows up. I've gone line by line in the code and it seems that `QgsApplication.initQgis()` is crashing Python. Any thoughts?

Comment: First guess, try with C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis\\ as prefix path.

Comment: Tried to no avail. Still get fatal pop-up window on that line

Comment: @brgionta - Try adding `QgsApplication( [], False, "C:\\Users\\You\\AppData\\Local\\Temp" )` **before** `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\\OSGeo4W\\apps\\qgis", True)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from qgis.core import *

import gdal
import qgis.utils

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis", True)

qgs = QgsApplication([], True)

qgs.initQgis()

print QgsApplication.showSettings()

layer = QgsVectorLayer('C:\Users\path to your shape\CB.shp', 'CB', 'ogr')

if not layer.isValid():

    print "Layer failed to load!"

else:

    print "Layer was loaded successfully!"

QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```